# How to retrieve the final URL destination while using the http package in Go?

Tags: go

Most sites redirect to another URL during a request. For example: `http://example.com might` might redirects to `http://mobile.example.com`

Is there a way to retrieve the final destination? In case of `cURL`, they call this the `effective URL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    getURL := "http://pkgdoc.org/"
    fmt.Println("getURL:", getURL)
    resp, err := http.Get(getURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    finalURL := resp.Request.URL.String()
    fmt.Println("finalURL:", finalURL)
}
```

Output:

```
getURL: http://pkgdoc.org/
finalURL: http://godoc.org/
```

Comment: I am not able to get the final url for "http://swiggy.com//google.com/%2f.." as google.com is a still getting swiggy.com itself any help ?