# Is there a way to expand shortened URLs in Go

Tags: url, go

I am writing a program that keeps track of different URLs and collects certain statistics about them. I have encountered many "shortened" URLs, and I was wondering if there is a way (or a package) in Go to expand shortened URLs?

Comment: Potentially useful: [In golang, how to determine the final URL after a series of redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16784419/142162)

Comment: Thanks for the link, exactly what I was looking for